# Kendo Mobile - Windows Phone 8 viewport broken on Lumia 920

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, kendo-ui

I am having issues with the Windows Phone 8 viewport on Lumia 920 devices. It doesn't seem to respect the standard viewport tag that kendo injects:

```
<meta content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

Does anyone know of any elegant workaround to get this working?

I am using Kendo v2013.1.319 with JQuery v1.9.1, as well as having all the latest updates/firmware upgrades on the Lumia 920.

Comment: Do you need the page to scroll up/down or left/right at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no viewport meta tag support in WP8, you have to use CSS [@-ms-viewport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However you don't need to, as Kendo UI Mobile already defines it.

If your main issue is the small interface elements, this is due to missing automatic scaling in WP8 IE10 (no window.devicePicelRatio) and is already fixed in the latest internal builds.

Comment: Thanks Bundyo. Yes, it is the small interface elements. Glad to hear it has been fixed in the latest internal builds. Have these builds been QC'd yet? If so, I can ask my boss to download it for our production environment.

Comment: Yes, they are produced from the production branch and get mostly fixes. They are also covered by tests and tested by our QA.

Comment: I am using kendo mobile Q2 Release 2013.2.716 and Internal Build 2013.2.910 -- both display image sizes as tiny instead of in a double-density manner. What scaling options for @-ms-viewport media queries should be applied to handle this? I tried @-ms-viewport { width: 320px; height: auto } but now text sizes are huge.

Comment: Also tried the Windows Phone 8 WXGA and 720p bug fix recommended at http://mattstow.com/responsive-design-in-ie10-on-windows-phone-8.html which handles image sizing well but now other interface elements are huge.
@-ms-viewport {
    /*width: device-width;*/
    width: auto!important;
}

Comment: I will need a test case to be able to answer. However, Kendo UI Mobile simulates devicePixelRatio on WP8 to be able to handle the resizing. You can use rem and em units to size your images.